# Select boxes - Display/No display

Tags: php, select

I have a page which allows users to comple one - three select boxes.

The first select box is shown on the page when it loads, then the user can click "Add filter 2/3/4"

See code below:

```
<div id="filter2"><a href="#">Add Filter 2</a></div>           
    <div id="filtertwo">           

      <label class="">Filter 2</label>
      <select class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Filter" name="filter2" data-init-plugin="select2">

      <option value="test">Test</option>
      <option value="test1">Test1</option>
      </select>   

    <script>
        $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#filter2").click(function() {
                $("#filtertwo").toggle();
            });
        });

    </script>

    <style>
         #filtertwo {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
```

The coding is the same for each of my select boxes. I would like to just show text "Add New Filter" only once, is this possible?

I have attached a screenshot so you can see my current page:
[image]

Comment: you mean you want to hide "Add New Filter" Link, when it clicked once??

Comment: Yes but also only show "Add New Filter" once - so once Filter 1 is completed, click "Add New" to show Filter 2, then click to show Filter 3 ect

Comment: You can hide your link after clicked it, code will be like `$("#filter2").hide()` and add a new Filter Link to add new Filters how many you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you post an answer with example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you properly. Consider following snippet:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#filter1,#filter2, #filter3").click(function() {
            $('.filter').hide();
            $(this).next('.filter').toggle();
        });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x82p8ubo/)

---

If you want to show only one filter link:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".filter-link").click(function() {
            $(".filter-link").hide();
            $(".filter-link").not(this).show();
            $('.filter').hide();
            $(this).next('.filter').toggle();
        });
    });
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/x82p8ubo/1/)

Comment: Thats very close to what I am wanting - Thank you! Is it possible to only show "add Filter" once?

Comment: The demo still shows "add filter 1" "add filter 2" is it not possible to just have "Add New Filter" and if 1 is complete open 2, then 3 ect?

Comment: I have given you idea. If you want so you have to write code for yourself.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure how to do what I am asking for

Comment: By the way, your updated demo doesnt show only one link filter

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="filter2"> <a id="filterLink" href="#"> Add New Filter </a> </div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#filter2").click(function() {
              $("#filtertwo").toggle();
              $("filterLink").hide();
              $("filter2").innerHTML = "<a id='filterLink' href='#'> Add Filter 2 </a>";
          });
     });
</script>
```

Now Repeat the code `innerHTML` how many time you want that link.

Comment: Thanks !! so would I just copy and paste `$("filter2").innerHTML = "<a id='filterLink' href='#'> Add Filter 2 </a>";
          });` and change filter2 to filter3 etc?

Comment: Yes, You can. it will made new links for you each and every time.